# Amazon Kinesis Analytics for archival data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, analytics, amazon-kinesis

**Background**

I have found that Amazon Kinesis Data Analytics can be used for streaming data as well as data present in an S3 bucket.

However, there are some parts of [the Kinesis documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/best-practices.html#bp-authoring-sqlcode) that make me question whether Amazon Kinesis Analytics can be used for a huge amount of existing data in an S3 bucket:

> ### Authoring Application Code
>
> We recommend the following:
>
> - In your SQL statement, don't specify a time-based window that is longer than one hour for the following reasons:
>
>   - Sometimes an application needs to be restarted, either because you updated the application or for Kinesis Data Analytics internal reasons. When it restarts, all data included in the window must be read again from the streaming data source. This takes time before Kinesis Data Analytics can emit output for that window.
>   - Kinesis Data Analytics must maintain everything related to the application's state, including relevant data, for the duration. This consumes significant Kinesis Data Analytics processing units.

**Question**

Will Amazon Kinesis Analytics be good for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary use case for Amazon Kinesis Analytics is stream data processing. For this reason, you attach an Amazon Kinesis Analytics application to a streaming data source. You can optionally include reference data from S3, which is limited in size to 1 GB at this time. We will load data from an S3 object into a SQL table that you can use to enrich the incoming stream.

It sounds like want a more general purpose tool for querying data from S3, not a stream data processing solution. I would recommend looking at Presto and Amazon EMR instead of using Amazon Kinesis Analytics.

Disclaimer: I work for the Amazon Kinesis team.

Comment: Amazon Athena launched in November 2016, so I would look at that as well:  https://aws.amazon.com/athena/